# jQuery/CSS - Full width on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three links, which will, onClick, show a different container (containing a chart). This is the HTML code for this:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <a class="select fs-11 uppercase active rentedref-chart" href="#">Rented</a>
    <a class="select fs-11 uppercase directref-chart" href="#">Direct</a>
    <a class="select fs-11 uppercase main-chart" href="#">Personal</a>

    <div id="rentedref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
    <div id="directref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;display:none;"></div>
    <div id="main-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;display:none;"></div>   
</div>
```

As you can see, only the first chart is shown on page load. In order for my users to see what charts they like, they can click the anchor links.

My jQuery code for this is:

```
$('.rentedref-chart').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.directref-chart').removeClass("active");
    $('.main-chart').removeClass("active");
    $('#directref-chart').hide();
    $('#main-chart').hide();
    $('#rentedref-chart').show();

});
$('.directref-chart').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.rentedref-chart').removeClass("active");
    $('.main-chart').removeClass("active");
    $('#rentedref-chart').hide();
    $('#main-chart').hide();
    $('#directref-chart').show();

});
$('.main-chart').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.directref-chart').removeClass("active");
    $('.rentedref-chart').removeClass("active");
    $('#directref-chart').hide();
    $('#rentedref-chart').hide();
    $('#main-chart').show();

});
```

Now, the switching between containers is working fine. My problem is, that the `#rentedref-chart`, `#directref-chart` and `#main-chart` all have `width:100%;`

The problem occurs, when the users switch to one of the containers/charts that is hidden. It will make the chart 100% of the page width, and not the container width.

How can I do, so the width is 100% of the container? (Like the first `#rented-chart` is on page load?)

**EDIT - SHOWING MORE CODE:**

This is the HTML structure:

```
<body>
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="col-xs-2">other content</div>
 <div class="col-xs-10 no-padding">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
        <a class="select fs-11 uppercase active rentedref-chart" href="#">Rented</a>
        <a class="select fs-11 uppercase directref-chart" href="#">Direct</a>
        <a class="select fs-11 uppercase main-chart" href="#">Personal</a>

        <div id="rentedref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
        <div id="directref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;display:none;"></div>
        <div id="main-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;display:none;"></div>   
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">other content</div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: `<div id="directref-chart" >` it's container or chart? From your explanation it's the same. And if it's the same - no problem exists :)

Comment: That's the chart container. Col-xs-8 is the "overall container"

Comment: did you add `$(document).ready(function(){ /* the code */ });` yet? it's work fine on me. check http://jsfiddle.net/6gg5o9gm/1/

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to show more code

Comment: What is important is what is being rendered inside the charts...

Comment: But the chart rendering doesn't set any width/css

Comment: @oliverbj charts often render incorrectly when you have hidden elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `display:none` from the charts and hide them on document ready. This allows the chart to be rendered at the correct size then hidden.

HTML

```
<div id="rentedref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
<div id="directref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
<div id="main-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('#directref-chart').hide();
    $('#main-chart').hide();
});
```

---

Alternatively if this is an option don't render your chart until it is selected for the first time. Use jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to achieve this.

```
$('.directref-chart').one("click", function() {
  //Render chart code.
});
```

Comment: Tried this. Even when hiding the charts with jQuery and not with CSS, they are still getting full page width. Col-xs-8 is the overall container

Comment: It's worth to mention, if the style display none is added, the width is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use the `display:none` there

Html

```
<div id="directref-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
<div id="main-chart" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#directref-chart').hide();
    $('#main-chart').hide();
});
```

Comment: Bad answer: no explanation.

Comment: i didnt its my answer too @AshleyMedway

Comment: That would be an invalid edit. I can't change the meaning of your post. If you don't understand my answer then don't rip it off.

Answer (score 0):

Do `position:absolute` for each element which have `width:100%`

This will work if there's no `position:relative` ( with specified `width` ) in whole `.col-xs-8`'s parent and your `.col-xs-8` with `position:absolute` and `width:100%` will fit the screen width.

The CSS :

```
body{ padding:0; margin:0 }
.col-xs-8{
   position:static;
   height:200px
   }
#rentedref-chart, #directref-chart, #main-chart{
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:auto;
   bottom:auto;
}
```

You should set `.cols-xs-8`'s `height` until the content under `.cols-xs-8` element shown.

I updated my fiddle before. http://jsfiddle.net/6gg5o9gm/6/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do it...
What I would suggest is create a class "asideanddntdisplay"

```
<style>
.asideanddntdisplay
 {position : fixed; left : -5000px;}
</style>
```

Before creating the chart :

```
 $("#directref-chart, #main-chart").show().addClass("asideanddntdisplay");
```

After the charts are created:

```
$("#directref-chart, #main-chart").hide().removeClass("asideanddntdisplay");
```

I believe this will work for you.